# How to show only the most recent of each unique entry

Tags: sql

This is a query I have written showing inspection outcomes, I am trying to show the most recent inspection on each enquiry so only need the most recent actual_inspection.logged_time to show with a unique central_enquiry.enquiry_number would appreciate any help

```
SELECT
   enquiry_subject.subject_name,
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number,
   central_site.site_name,
   CAST((SELECT parameter_value.param_value_name FROM parameter_value,parameter_type WHERE parameter_type.param_type_code = 'S815' AND parameter_value.param_value_code = enquiry_attribute.param_value_code AND parameter_value.param_type_code = 'S815') as VARCHAR (30)) as Promoter,
   CAST((SELECT parameter_value.param_value_name FROM parameter_value,parameter_type WHERE parameter_type.param_type_code = 'S818' AND parameter_value.param_value_code = enquiry_attribute_5.param_value_code AND parameter_value.param_type_code = 'S818' ) as VARCHAR (30)) as severity,
   enquiry_status.enq_status_name,
   central_enquiry.log_text,
   sw_header.works_ref,
   sw_notice_header.notice_issue_time,
   sw_notice_header.work_start_date,
   sw_notice_header.work_est_end_date,
   sw_notice_header.work_comp_date,
   sw_notice_header.notice_type_code,
   notice_type.notice_type_name,
   sw_notice_header.works_desc,
   sw_notice_header.works_location,
   sw_works_status.works_status_name,
   actual_inspection.logged_time,
   actual_inspection.logged_by,
   actual_inspection.insp_number,
   actual_inspection.insp_outcome_code,
   actual_inspection.insp_notes,
   CASE
WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=60 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 10000  THEN 'Over 60 Days'
   WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=30 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 60  THEN '30 - 60 Days'
   WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=15 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 29.99  THEN '15 - 30 Days'
   WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=5 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 14.99  THEN '5 - 15 Days'
   WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=2 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 4.99  THEN '2 - 5 Days'
   WHEN ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) >=0 AND ROUND((program_insp.insp_to_date -SYSDATE),2) <= 1.99  THEN 'Today | Tomorrow'
   ELSE 'Overdue' END as this_week,
   program_insp.insp_to_date,
   program_insp.insp_from_date
FROM
   enquiry_subject,
   enquiry_status_log,
   enquiry_status,
   enquiry_class,
   type_of_service,
   ward,
   enquiry_attribute,
   enquiry_attribute enquiry_attribute_2,
   enquiry_attribute enquiry_attribute_3,
   enquiry_attribute enquiry_attribute_4,
   enquiry_attribute enquiry_attribute_5,
   central_enquiry,
   actual_inspection,  
   sw_header
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_notice_header
ON
   sw_header.work_version_no = sw_notice_header.work_version_no AND
   sw_header.work_header_no = sw_notice_header.work_header_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_site
ON
   sw_site.work_header_no = sw_notice_header.work_header_no AND
   sw_site.site_number = sw_notice_header.primary_site_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_notice_site
ON
   sw_site.work_header_no = sw_notice_site.work_header_no AND
   sw_site.work_version_no = sw_notice_site.work_version_no AND
   sw_site.site_number = sw_notice_site.site_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   central_site
ON
   sw_notice_site.site_code = central_site.site_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   locality
ON
   central_site.locality_id = locality.locality_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   town
ON
   locality.town_id = town.town_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   street_work_type
ON
   sw_notice_header.street_work_code = street_work_type.street_work_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   area
ON
   central_site.area_code = area.area_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_agreement
ON
   sw_agreement.work_version_no = sw_notice_header.work_version_no AND
   sw_agreement.work_header_no = sw_notice_header.work_header_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   organisation
ON
   organisation.organise_code = sw_header.organise_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   organise_group
ON
   organise_group.org_group_code = organisation.org_group_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   notice_type
ON
   notice_type.notice_type_code = sw_notice_header.notice_type_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_works_status
ON
   sw_works_status.works_status_code = sw_notice_header.works_status_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   traffic_manage
ON
   traffic_manage.traffic_code = sw_notice_site.traffic_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sw_excavation
ON
   sw_excavation.excavation_code = sw_notice_header.excavation_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   site_category
ON
   site_category.category_code = central_site.category_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   program_insp
ON 
   program_insp.work_header_no = sw_header.work_header_no


WHERE
sw_header.work_header_no = actual_inspection.work_header_no AND
sw_header.works_ref IN ('1303465') AND
 type_of_service.service_code = enquiry_subject.service_code AND
   enquiry_subject.service_code = central_enquiry.service_code AND
   enquiry_subject.subject_code = central_enquiry.subject_code AND
   central_enquiry.enq_class_code = enquiry_class.enq_class_code AND
   central_site.site_code = central_enquiry.site_code AND
   central_site.area_code = area.area_code AND
   central_site.ward_code = ward.ward_code AND
   central_site.category_code = site_category.category_code AND
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_attribute.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_attribute.param_type_code = 'S815' AND
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_attribute_2.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_attribute_2.param_type_code = 'S816' AND
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_attribute_3.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_attribute_3.param_type_code = 'S817' AND
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_attribute_4.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_attribute_4.param_type_code = 'S814' AND
   central_enquiry.enquiry_number = enquiry_attribute_5.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_attribute_5.param_type_code = 'S818' AND
   type_of_service.service_code = 'SW' AND
   enquiry_subject.subject_code = '06' AND
   enquiry_status.enq_status_code = central_enquiry.enq_status_code AND
   enquiry_status_log.enquiry_number = central_enquiry.enquiry_number AND
   enquiry_status_log.enquiry_log_number = central_enquiry.enquiry_log_number AND
   enquiry_status.enq_status_code NOT IN ('50')
```

I am thinking I need to use a select MAX and then group by but not 100% how to execute this

Comment: Don't mix comma separated, implicit joins and explicit JOIN's. Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. I.e. show us some sample table data and also the expected result - all as properly formatted text (no images, no links.) And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: thats a long code, and did you try utilizing a subquery to filter out the older inspections

Comment: Table aliases are handy and saves lots of typing.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` would work, but I'd use a window function instead. Something like:

```
select *
from
(    
   select ...,
          ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by central_enquiry.enquiry_number
                             order by actual_inspection.logged_time desc) rn
   from ...
) dt
where rn = 1
```

For each distinct central_enquiry.enquiry_number value, order - and number - the rows by actual_inspection.logged_time descending. Pick the first row, i.e. the most recent one.